# How can i transparent of a textformfield?

Tags: flutter

[image]

```
child: Container(
          height: context.preferredSize.height,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
            color: context.colors.background,
          ),
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.mic),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 4,
                child: Theme(
                  data: Theme.of(context)
                      .copyWith(splashColor: Colors.transparent),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    cursorWidth: 4,
                    cursorHeight: 20,
                    cursorColor: Colors.white,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    maxLines: 1,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      if (value.isNotEmpty) {}
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Guys, my question is clear. How can I make the textformfield background transparent? I want the TextFormField to get the color of the container.

Comment: Whats the problem there? That should already worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your theme is affecting your `InputDecoration`. Check your `MaterialApp` `theme:` for something like this:

```
inputDecorationTheme:
          InputDecorationTheme(fillColor: Colors.white, filled: true)
```

This code is causing all your children widgets that depend on `InputDecorationTheme` to use `fillColor: Colors.white, filled: true`.

Here is the recreation of the issue you are facing:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
          splashColor: Colors.white,
          inputDecorationTheme:
              InputDecorationTheme(fillColor: Colors.white, filled: true)),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      cursorWidth: 4,
      cursorHeight: 20,
      cursorColor: Colors.white,
      style: const TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output:
[image]

There are 3 solutions:

**Solution 1:**

```
TextFormField(
  cursorWidth: 4,
  cursorHeight: 20,
  cursorColor: Colors.white,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    fillColor: Colors.transparent,
    filled: true,
  ),
  style: const TextStyle(
    color: Colors.white,
  ),
)
```

Explanation:
setting

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
    fillColor: Colors.transparent,
    filled: true,
  ),
```

will override what ever is being provided by the theme

**Solution 2:**
remove

```
inputDecorationTheme:
          InputDecorationTheme(fillColor: Colors.white, filled: true))
```

from your `MaterialApp` theme.

Explanation:
by default, it should be transparent if you don't set it.

**Solution 3:**
Wrap `textfield` with `Theme` to override all the children to use new theme settings.

```
Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context)
          .copyWith(inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme()),
      child: TextFormField(
        cursorWidth: 4,
        cursorHeight: 20,
        cursorColor: Colors.white,
        style: const TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Explanation:
Wrapping your widget with `Theme` and setting `data:` will provide a new theme for **all of the widgets below it**.

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed solutions. I tried of solution 1 is worked in perfectly.